# How to set different "proxy_cache_valid" parameter per page type?

Tags: nginx

I have 3 type of pages:

1. Static Pages (For example: /about, /contact)
2. Category Pages (For example: /tags, /movies, /actors)
3. Item Pages (For example: /movies/avatar, /actors/angelina-jolie

Page url can be changed under the Back-office, so i can't add it manually
to nginx.conf file.

I want:

1. Static pages - 1 day cache expiration
2. Category pages - 3 days cache expiration
3. Item Pages - 1 week cache expiration

Is it possible to configure different expiration for each type?

Thanks

Comment: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_valid «Parameters of caching can also be set directly in the response header… The “X-Accel-Expires” header field sets caching time of a response in seconds. »

Comment: Thank you, i will check it!